# C# load Dll dynamically without finding its dependencies

Tags: c#, reflection

I read this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069201/load-a-dll-and-its-dependencies), but it doesn't help me.

My goal is to find the class that has custom attributes.
since I don't need any instance or use codes, is there a way to load DLL file and search what I want in code, without solving dependencies problem? to lookup codes.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/how-to-load-assemblies-into-the-reflection-only-context

Comment: thank you for the reply, I didn't even know there is an MSDN article that describes this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you going to get all app domain assemblies types you can avoid that issue by catching the `ReflectionTypeLoadException`:

```
public static class AssemblyExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetLoadableTypes(this Assembly assembly)
    {
        if (assembly == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(assembly));
        try
        {
            return assembly.GetTypes();
        }
        catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException e)
        {
            return e.Types.Where(t => t != null);
        }
    }
}
```

you can use it like so:

```
var types = (from domainAssembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(x => !x.IsDynamic)
             from assemblyType in domainAssembly.GetLoadableTypes()
             select assemblyType);
```

if you targeting an assembly you want to load it without loading its dependencies use one of overloads:
as documented here: [How to: Load Assemblies into the Reflection-Only Context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/how-to-load-assemblies-into-the-reflection-only-context)

```
Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(/*your appropriate parameter assembly name or something else*/);
```